# Ethernet router not working on Ubuntu 18.04 system

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet

I have an Ethernet router that is not working on Ubuntu 18.04. The Ethernet connection did not work on the installation media, so I figure it can’t be the Ubuntu installation. Different ports don’t work; I’ve done `sudo ip link set enp4s0 down` and `up` but it doesn’t work. Everything I do gives me network connection failed message. I even tried unplugging the router and plugging it in again. I have looked on various websites and could not find anything specific to my situation. The router is Netgear if that might be relevant.

Is there something to fix this? Some magic command?

Comment: please explain what leads you to believe that the problem is not related to Linux? ... why would you post a question here if you believe that the problem is not related to Linux?

Comment: I think it might be and that’s why I’m asking it here. Just mentioning the router brand in case that could be relevant to any answers

Comment: Just put it in the main post so it doesn’t look like I’m posting something unrelated to Linux

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution that might help you. Here are the steps for you to follow.
1)
Goto following file and add eth0 and eth1 If you have two network interfaces
sudo vim /etc/network/interfaces

## The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

## The primary network interface

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

2)
Remove following line
sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

3)
Restart
sudo reboot